# Access user channel

Tags: youtube-api

I'm transitioning an app from api v2 to v3. I understand that channels map to the old video author. However, for a video such as this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBlSHIBUx7g, it identifies the channel id as UCfjXVOHS-WLeTB4-60Lz_Uw, which is titled "Extreme sports Extreme sports". Whereas the channel id of the author (Red Bull) is UCblfuW_4rakIf2h6aqANefA.

How can I map through to the channel title for the parent channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it actually shows the RedBull channel.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&id=dBlSHIBUx7g&_h=1&

Answer (score 0):

It seems my client (the [yt gem](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt)) is passing other extra parameters to my search, so in fact it is returning a different video than simply using the API explorer. Hence the mismatch